# Cactus with pink spines at top?

Tags: identification, plant-care, cactus

Received this cactus and couldn't find it online what cactus this is. Care tips would be nice.

[image]

[image]

Location: New Delhi
Pot size is 4"

Answer (score 1):

A known phenomena among ferocactus species - this one possibly f. Herrerae,

[Juvenile spines at the tip are pink](https://www.cactusjungle.com/plants/ferocactus-herrerae/) at the growth tip.

Comment: The spunyes are straight and not hooked. Only 2-3 spines are hooked.

Comment: Can OP describe the growing conditions? Is this an indoor plant? How much direct sun does it get? Has it ever been fertilized? I didn't think Ferocactus because of the columnar habit shown rather than the normal depressed globose form. New spines showing pink, red, white coloration is not an unusual event in cactus. This "sort of "looks like a few different species.

Comment: @TimNevins Is it Coville's barrel Cactus?